# How to extract Shape and Texture vertices from .wrl(VRML) file to .mat

Tags: matlab

I have 3D data. And there is a .wrl(VRML) file in it. I need to load that file and then extract only the shape and texture vertices (x,y,z)points. How to do that?

This is the code i have:

```
%/*********************************************************************************
% FUNCTION NAME : read_vrml
% AUTHOR        : G. Akroyd
% PURPOSE  : reads a VRML or Inventor file and stores data points and connectivity
%             in arrays ready for drawing wireframe images.
%
% VARIABLES/PARAMETERS: 
%  i/p  filename       name of vrml file 
%  o/p  nel            number of geometry parts (elements) in file
%  o/p  w3d            geometry structure ;-
%                       w3d.pts   array of x y z values for each element                      
%                       w3d.knx   array of connection nodes for each element
%                       w3d.color color of each element
%                       w3d.polynum number of polygons for each element
%                       w3d.trans  transparency of each element
%
% Version / Date : 3.0   / 23-9-02
%                  removed triang optn & replaced face array Nan padding
%                   with 1st value padding to correct opengl display prob.
% Version / Date : 2.0   / 17-7-00
%                  changed output to a structure rather than separate arrays
%                   to use less memory.
%                  1.0   / 21-6-99
%                  original version
%**********************************************************************************/

function [nel,w3d,infoline] = read_vrml(filename)

keynames=char('Coordinate3','point','coordIndex');

  fp = fopen(filename,'r');
  if fp == -1
  fclose all;
  str = sprintf('Cannot open file %s \n',filename);
  errordlg(str);
  error(str);
  end

%* initialise arrays & counters */
  fv = zeros(1,3);
  foundkey=zeros(1,3); %* flags to determine if keywords found */
  endpts=0; %/* flag set when end of co-ord pts reached for an element */
  npt=0; %/* counter for num pts or conections */
  npol=1; % counter for number of polygons in an element
  nel=1; %/* counter for num of elements */
  color(1,1:3) = [0.5 0.55 0.5]; % default color
  maxnp = 0;
  tempstr = ' ';
  lastel = 1;
  lnum = 1;
  w3d(1).name = 'patch1';
  infoline = '#';
  trnsp(1) = 1; % transparency array - one val per element

  %/* start of main loop for reading file line by line */
  while ( tempstr ~= -1)
     tempstr = fgets(fp); % -1 if eof 
     if tempstr(1) == '#' & lnum == 2,
        infoline = tempstr;
     end 
     lnum = lnum +1; % line counter
     if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,'DEF')) & ~endpts,
        w3d(nel).name = sscanf(tempstr,'%*s %s %*s %*s');
     end

     if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,'rgb')) | ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,'diffuseColor')) % get color data 
     sp = findstr(tempstr,'[');
     if isempty(sp), sp = 12 + findstr(tempstr,'diffuseColor'); end
     nc = 0;
     if ~isempty(sp)
        sp = sp +1;                          
        [cvals,nc]=sscanf(tempstr(sp:length(tempstr)),'%f %f %f,');
     end
     if nc >= 3
        if nel > lastel+1 
           for m = lastel+1:nel-1
              color(m,1:3) = color(1,1:3); % if color not set then make equal to 1st 
           end 
        end 
        % if multi colors set then populate color matrix, this is an inventor feature
        for s = 1:fix(nc/3) 
              color(s+nel-1,1:3) = cvals(3*s-2:3*s)'; 
           lastel = s+nel-1;
        end    
     end 
 end 
 if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,'transparency')), % get transparency level
     sp = findstr(tempstr,'trans');
     [tvals,nc]=sscanf(tempstr(sp+12:length(tempstr)),'%f');
     if nc > 0, trnsp(nel) = tvals(1); end
 end 

 for i=1:3  %/* check for each keyword in line */
    key = deblank(keynames(i,:));
    if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,key)) & isempty(findstr(tempstr,'#')) 
       %/* if key found again before all found there is a problem
       %  so reset flag for that key */
       if ~foundkey(i), foundkey(i)=1;else foundkey(i)=0; end
       if(i>1 & ~foundkey(i-1)) foundkey(i)=0; end %/* previous key must exist first ! */
    end
 end
 if(foundkey(1) & foundkey(2)) %/* start of if A  first 2 keys found */
     if foundkey(3) %/* scan for connectivity data */
        tempstr = [tempstr,' #']; %/* last word marker for end of line */
        skip = '';
        %/* loop puts integer values in a line into connection array */
        word = ' ';
        while(word(1) ~= '#')
           format = sprintf('%s %%s#',skip);
           [word,nw] = sscanf(tempstr,format);
           skip = [skip,'%*s'];
           [node,nred] = sscanf(word,'%d,');
           if nred>0 
              for p = 1:nred
                 if node(p) ~= -1 
                    npt = npt +1; 
                    % increment node value as matlab counts from 1, vrml 0
                    w3d(nel).knx(npol,npt) = node(p)+1;
                 else
                    if npt > maxnp(nel), maxnp(nel) = npt; end 
                    npt = 0;
                    npol = npol + 1; 
                 end
              end
           end              
        end

        if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,']')) %/* End of data block marker */
           polynum(nel)=npol-1; %/* store num of polygons in this element */
           endpts=0; %/* reset flag ready for next element search */
           npt=0;
           npol=1;
           foundkey = zeros(1,4); %/* reset keyword flags for next search */
           nel = nel+1; %/* now looking for next element so increment counter 
           maxnp(nel) = 0;
           w3d(nel).name = sprintf('patch%d',nel); % name next block
        end
     end %/* end of scan for connectivity */

     %/* got 1st 2 keys but not 3rd and not end of co-ords data */
     if(foundkey(2) & ~foundkey(3) & ~endpts) %/* scan for pts data */
        sp = findstr(tempstr,'[');
        if isempty(sp)
           %/* points data in x y z columns */
           [fv,nv]=sscanf(tempstr,'%f %f %f,');
        else
           %/* if block start marker [ in line - need to skip over it to data 
           %   hence pointer to marker incremented */
           sp = sp +1;
           [fv,nv]=sscanf(tempstr(sp:length(tempstr)),'%f %f %f,');
        end
        if(nv>0)
           if mod(nv,3) ~= 0
              fclose(fp);
              error('Error reading 3d wire co-ordinates: should be x y z, on each line');
           end 
           nov = fix(nv/3);
           for p = 1:nov
              npt = npt+1;
              w3d(nel).pts(npt,1:3)=fv(3*p-2:3*p); 
           end
        end                  
        if ~isempty(findstr(tempstr,']')) %/* end of pts data block */
           endpts=1; %/* flag to stop entry to pts scan while reading connections */
           npt=0;
        end
     end %/* end of scan for data pts */
 end %/* end of if A */     
end %/* end of main loop */

if nel == 0
    fclose(fp);
    error('Error reading 3d file: no data found');
end
nel = nel -1; 

% if not same number of verticies in each polygon we need to fill
% out rest of row in array with 1st value
nc = size(color); 
ts = size(trnsp);

for i = 1:nel 
facs = w3d(i).knx;
ind1 = find(facs==0); [rown,coln] = ind2sub(size(facs),ind1);
facs(ind1) = facs(rown);
w3d(i).knx = facs;
if i > 1 & i > nc(1), color(i,1:3) = color(1,1:3); end % extend color array to cover all elements 
w3d(i).color = color(i,1:3);
w3d(i).polynum = polynum(i);
if i > ts(2) | trnsp(i)==0, 
    trnsp(i) = 1; 
end % extend transparency array to cover all elements 
w3d(i).trans = trnsp(i);
end

fclose(fp);

%  END OF FUNCTION read_vrml

%=====================================================================================
```

Here i have just replaced filename with sub1.wrl which is my vrml file.
It gives the following error

> > read_vrml
> >     Error using read_vrml (line 31)
> >     Not enough input arguments.

And if i edit ...function [nel,w3d,infoline] = read_vrml() 
i.e to not enter anything only at the place of first occurrence of filename.
It gives error

> > read_vrml
> >     Undefined variable "sub1" or class "sub1.wrl".

Error in read_vrml (line 31)
  fp = fopen(sub1.wrl,'r');

Comment: have you looked into this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3583-read-vrml

Comment: @CapeCode yes i have. I downloaded the code but it gives the error.  the name of my .wrl file is sub1.wrl. when ever i enter this instead of file name it gives error saying that more arguments are required. It would be very kind of you to help solve this.

Comment: Edit your question with your code and the exact error message.

Comment: @CapeCode can you check now.

Comment: Any luck with my suggestions?

Comment: @CapeCode can i have your e-mail id? I am having problems in plotting the figure with color.

Comment: Post a new question with your other problem and give me the link here, I'll look at it. If my answer here was helpful you can accept it to show that this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the way functions are to be used.

**Save** the function into your matlab directory.
Then in your console/script **call** the function like this:

```
MySurf=read_vrml('sub1.wrl');
```

If you try to put your file name instead of the argument in the function definition, it will fail. Also, in Matlab, file names are arrays of characters (strings), you need to use quotation marks (`'`) to identify a string.

Answer (score -1):

### SYNTAX-wise

```
fp = fopen( 'sub1.wrl', 'r' );         %% 'un-quoted' string was considered a variable
```

### VRML-wise

The cleanest / the most straightforward would be to pre-process the **`.wrl`** file ( with a use of **`regex`** et al ) to retrieve the VRML-code decomposed [ x, y, z] data and to allow a pipe-line processing thereof

Comment: This is the wrong syntax. We don't use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for a comment, Maha. The important was the idea, not the syntax-glitch.